# Filtering a List based on a Suffix and avoid duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I was wondering if there is a better way to solve this issue.

I have a list like this:

```
imp_list=["aa","daa","ab","as","aem",
      "aum","aw","aa","acm","at",
      "ar","aa_imp","daa_imp","ab_imp",
      "as_imp"]
```

I want to select all the strings that have the **`_imp` suffix**, plus all the the strings that have no `_imp` partner.

That's because `aa_imp` it's just a modified version of `aa`, and for me, in a large sense, it's a replica.
So I created this function:

```
def imputed_handler(my_list): 
  imp=[x for x in my_list if "imp" in x]

  cleaned_imp=set(map(lambda x: x.replace("_imp",""),imp))

  not_imp=[x for x in my_list if "imp" not in x]
  set_list=set(my_list)
  no_replica=list(set_list-cleaned_imp)
  print(no_replica)
  return no_replica
```

Running the code as described above

```
test=imputed_handler(imp_list)
```

I get the following output:

```
['at', 'acm', 'aw', 'ar', 'daa_imp', 'aem', 'as_imp', 'ab_imp', 'aa_imp', 'aum']
```

Do better solutions exist? Thanks for your time, and let me know if something is not clear :)

Comment: "Do better solutions exist?" - Yes, for example the one that doesn't compute `not_imp` and then never uses it :-P

Comment: @KellyBundy lol you are right and you make my day :)

Comment: What's with the function _name_, would you like to have it reviewed? Or is this a no-touch constraint?

Comment: @hc_dev yep it can be reviewed! I am self-taught so if there is something wrong I really appreciate it! <3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, since you're looking for strings that end with `_imp`, `x.endswith("_imp")` is probably more reliable than `"imp" in x`.

Second, since we only want to remove `_imp` when it's a suffix, and since we know how long it is, we can use string slicing to remove the last 4 characters. That means we don't accidentally turn `x_impabc_imp` into `xabc` instead of `x_impabc` or something. Assuming that's not what we want to do. Maybe it is, maybe it isn't, maybe we'll never get an input like that so it won't matter either way, I have no idea.

I'm also thinking it might be nice to pass the suffix as a parameter. Maybe it might change at some point in the future. Maybe another part of the program uses a different suffix in a similar way. Doesn't hurt to be prepared.

In general, though, your approach is good. You find the `_imp` ones, you figure out what they are replacing, you remove the ones that have been replaced.

The neat thing is, you can do the first two steps all at once in a single pass through the input list. For example, you can do this:

```
def imputed_handler(my_list, suffix="_imp"):
    my_set = set(my_list)
    cleaned_imp = set(item[:-len(suffix)] for item in my_set if item.endswith(suffix))

    return list(my_set - cleaned_imp)
```

Though a loop might be clearer at that point:

```
def imputed_handler(my_list, suffix="_imp"):
    my_set = set(my_list)

    for item in my_list:
        if item.endswith(suffix):
            my_set.discard(item[:-len(suffix)])

    return list(my_set)
```

Comment: Since Python 3.9 you can also use `item.removesuffix(suffix)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh, neat. I didn't find that since I'm still on 3.8.5 for some reason, but that's good to know.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the line `cleaned_imp = set(item[:-len(suffix)] for item in my_set if item.endswith(suffix))` will call `len(suffix)` and calculate `-len(suffix)` for every item. So it's usually better to calculate it once and use it as a variable inside the generator expression.

Answer (score 9):

## PEP 8

The [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) lists several conventions Python programs should follow.  Things like:

- spaces around binary operators (`imp = [...]` and `set_list = set(my_list)`).
- spaces after comma (eg, `""), imp))`

## Side Effects

You are returning a result from `imputed_hander`; shouldn't print from inside it.

## Type Hints and Doc Strings

What is `def imputed_handler(my_list)`?  What does it do?  What is `my_list` a list of?  What is returned?

```py
from typing import List

def imputed_handler(my_list: List[str]) -> List[str]: 
    """
    Filter a list of strings, removing `"xyz"` if `"xyz_imp"` is found.
    Return the filtered list.
    """
```

Now we have a (poor) description, and can see the argument & return types.

## Improved code

As mentioned in [Sara J's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/255816/100620), `.endswith()` is preferable to simply checking if the search string is contained anywhere inside the original.

Converting the list into a set, and then back into a list ruins the original lists order.  Here is a possible improvement on Sara's solution:

```py
from typing import List

def imputed_handler(my_list: List[str], suffix: str = "_imp") -> List[str]:
    """
    A good description here.
    """

    unwanted = {item.removesuffix(suffix) for item in my_list if item.endswith(suffix)}
    return [item for item in my_list if item not in unwanted]
```

A `set` is only constructed from the prefix of items which end in `_imp`.  This should result in a smaller memory footprint, that `set(my_list) - cleaned_imp`.  Since it is a `set`, the `in` operator is \$O(1)\$, filtering the list is fast.

Comment: Note, [`typing.List` is now deprecated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/#implementation) you can just use `list[str]` in Python 3.9+ or import annotations from PEP 563 - "Importing those from `typing` is deprecated. Due to [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563) and the intention to minimize the runtime impact of typing, this deprecation will not generate DeprecationWarnings."

Comment: One more possible tweak is instead of taking "foo_imp" and generating "foo" to discard, is to ask for each "foo" whether "foo_imp" is in the set.  `my_set = set(my_list); return [s for s in my_list if s + suffix not in my_set]`.  Need to be careful whether it's equivalent for chains such as `imputed_handler(["aa", "aa_imp", "aa_imp_imp"])` but I think it is...  This also matches your description "removing `"xyz"` if `"xyz_imp"` is found" which is the clearest definition I can think of.